# How to get routes working on shared hosting space

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Pretty new to backend dev.

I'm having trouble getting routes from a React app to work on my shared hosting space whenever refreshing /some-page. Locally I got it working with express but I'm not sure how to get it working on the shared space.

**Express config:**

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, "index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is up!");
});
```

**Webpack config:**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isProduction = env === "production";

  console.log(`env: ${env}`);
  return {
    mode: "none",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "public", "dist"),
      filename: "bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            { loader: "style-loader" },
            { loader: "css-loader" },
            { loader: "sass-loader" },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                outputPath: "img/",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
  };
};
```

**Package.json scripts:**

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-dev": "webpack",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "start": "node server/server.js"
  },
```

How do I get the express config working on the shared hosting server to have everything running like it does locally? I only have what's inside the dist folder uploaded with ftp on the shared space now.

Shared hosting account is at Siteground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got this working by redirecting all traffic to the index.html for all routes != "/", but not necessarily using the express backend code, bc of the shared hosting limitations obviously.